# IndexError: list index out of range on selective inputs to a python function's parameter

Tags: python

This is a program to get the first five queries from google. I have it as a function. I have combined codes and tailored to program to work. Oddly it works only sometimes. Sometimes I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 36, in <module>
    run(i)
  File "google.py", line 21, in run
    link='http'+split_content[1].split(':http',1)[1].split('%',1)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It's worked all times on simple words. However on some names (which I cannot unfortunately reveal which names due to privacy policy) the name is 'xxxxx xxxxx' format, however when I test 'Lebron James', it worked.

The while loop is from another person's program. Somewhere something is happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# this is the logic in order to get the first 5
# queries off of google.com

import requests
import sys
import webbrowser

def run(word_to_search):

    request = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q='+word_to_search)
    content=request.content.decode('UTF-8','replace')

    links=[]
    while '<h3 class="r">' in content:
        content=content.split('<h3 class="r">', 1)[1]
        split_content=content.split('</h3>', 1)
        link='http'+split_content[1].split(':http',1)[1].split('%',1)[0]
        links.append(link)
        content=split_content[1]

    file = open("google.txt","a")
    file.write("\n\n"+word_to_search+"\n")

    for link in links[:5]:  # max number of links 5
        file.write(link + "\n")



list = ['Curly','Moe','Shorty','Laser Beams']

for i in list:
   run(i)
```

The successful program outputs this:

```
Curly
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/curly
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/curly
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curly_Howard
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/curly
https://www.naturallycurly.com/


Moe
http://www.moe.org/
http://www.moe.org/tour_date/
https://www.facebook.com/moe.org/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_(slang)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_(band)


Shorty
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shorty
http://www.mdaniels.com/shorty/
http://shortyawards.com/


Laser Beams
http://www.lazerbrody.typepad.com/
http://www.lazerbrody.typepad.com/
https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_beams.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser
http://spaceshipsandlaserbeams.com/
```

Comment: Do those names that don't work return at least 5 results in Google?

Comment: Yes if I were to go to Google, the names that don't return/work do in fact have 5 results in Google. I am currently trying to write a try and except block... maybe you could help me there and I could just cut my losses? This is being run for lots of names so if a few are missing I will still live. Here is my code so far:

`while True:
    for i in list:
        try:
            run(i)
            break
        except IndexError:
            pass`